# Register as client to GCM

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am testing a server that uses google cloud messaging (GCM)
In order to perform the test without an actual device (for a faster way and actually test only the server side)
I am looking for a way to register as a client **WITHOUT** a device
I have from the server the **project id** and the **sender id**
 
But I see that I need an **instanse id** of the client in order to register to GCM (via https: //android.googleapis.com/gcm/send)
Is it possible to generate an instance id without an actual client?

P.S.

Maybe it will help I have found this code of [Angular GCM client](https://github.com/Thom-x/angular-gcm), and [Python GCM client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gcm-client/)
but i couldn't succeeded to find a solution for registration yet
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can remove the "client app" out of the equation as it is part of the [architectural components of GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm):

> A GCM implementation includes a Google connection server, an app
>   server in your environment that interacts with the connection server
>   via HTTP or XMPP protocol, and a client app.

However if you meant, without a real device, try using the emulator.

Comment: Thanks, i will check it out